# Discord Intents code for get all events from gateway

Tags: javascript, websocket, discord, gateway

i'm trying to connect to Discord gateway, but i didn't receive all events (like MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, all threads events and more) because I don't know the intent code for get all events.

Payload that I actually send to Discord:

```
    let payload = {
      op: 2,
      d: {
        token: "bot token",
        intents: 513,
        properties: {
          $os: "linux",
          $browser: "chrome",
          $device: "chrome",
        },
      },
    };
```

My current intent code doesn't works for all events.
What code I need to insert for get all events? 
Discord documentation isn't very clean about this.
Thanks in advice and sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every intent you can use `32767`, to find what the number you need to add together all the intents you need. Each number is listen in the [documentation here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents). So if I wanted to have `GUILDS`, `GUILD_MESSAGES`, `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`, and `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING` and  I would just add together `1 << 0`, `1 << 9`, `1 << 10`, and `1 << 11` which is `3585`.

Comment: Hi, how you did this calculation and you got 32767 ? What if i only want to listen to custom emojis of a message in a chat room ? to specify, the verification emoji ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift

The operation can be done in a js console : 1 << 0 == 1